# When I turn on my computer, I'm stuck on this: [open for photo]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.04. It is also my first ever Linux machine. I was installing the Nvidia drivers following this guide: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/

Then it shut down... so I turned it back on, and now it's stuck on this, it's just flashing and running the same thing over and over again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZomvS.jpg

Any help? I've tried holding down the power button to shut down the PC, then turning it back on, and it'll jump right back here.

Note: nothing is plugged into the graphics card, I have 1 monitor plugged into the motherboard.

Relevant Specs:

1. CPU: i7 6700K
2. GPU: GTX 970
3. MOBO: Asus Z170-A

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by reinstalling Ubuntu 19.04. After reinstalling, Ubuntu automatically recognized and installed the proper/correct Nvidia drivers, unlike the first time I had installed Ubuntu 19.04.